# Change project of a deployed script, and I couldn't unpublished the previous one

Tags: google-apps-script

I have just updated an old Google Apps Script for Google Spreadsheet.
Due to new updates requirements I have been requested to create a new project in Google Cloud to be able to update it.

The problem appears when the [old script](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/smartmonkeyio_route_optimizer_for_google/80526361570) (has >5.000 users) once I changed to a [new one](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/route_optimizer_for_google_spreadsheet/59979660028), the system didn't updated it at all and just create a new plugin. The update has been made in the same Script file, just changing the project. The old one was the default project which is now unavailable.

The worst part is that I don't know how to unpublish the old one as it has been deprecated the service it's using it.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked all the steps on [Upgrading your published add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/upgrade-addons)?

Comment: GREAT, didn't know the specific process to follow and I've just upgraded a public one. Any idea how to continue? at least how to unpublish the old one, even if I lose thousands of users?

Answer (score -1):

Replying as an answer for the new comment and the question itself:

To Upgrade your published add-on the instruction are explained on the link:

- [Upgrading your published add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/upgrade-addons)

To unpublish an add-on the instructions are on the link:

- [Update or unpublish an app listing](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/manage-app-listing)

> To unpublish your app listing, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open your app’s Cloud Platform project in the Google Cloud Platform >console.
> 2. At the top left, click Menu menu > APIs & Services.
> 3. In the list at the bottom, click Google Workspace Marketplace SDK.
> 4. At the left, click Store Listing.
> 5. Click Unpublish. To republish, follow the above steps and click Publish.
>
> After you unpublish, your app listing no longer appears on Google Workspace Marketplace or the chatbot catalog, and users who have already installed your app can no longer access it. If you republish, the users who had previously installed your app regain access.

Comment: This is for regular one, but didn't answer the question asked